# Reading an Image URL from XML using XSL to display web page in web browser

Tags: android, ios, xml, image, xslt

I am formating an xml file using xsl. Part of this involves reading an image URL from the XML file and then displaying the image in a web browser. I have tried two different methods of doing this and both methods work when viewed using firefox, Internet Explorer or Edge on a windows machine.

When I try to view this using Safari or Firefox on an iphone using IOS 10 the document displays correctly except for the image not being displayed. I have also tried this on an Android phone with the same result - no image displayed. My question is can this be done on IOS (or Android) phone web browsers?

The source xml file is below (with unrelated tags to image removed)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="application/xml" href="whats_on.xsl"?>
<show_details>

<production>
    <show_title>
        Hobsons Choice
    </show_title>
    <show_image>
        <image_path>
            ../images/show_images/hobsons_choice/hobsons_choice.jpg
        </image_path>
        <image_alt_text>
            Hobsons Choice
        </image_alt_text>
    </show_image>
    ... More tags here
</production>
... More tags here
</show_details>
```

The XSL file to format the document with sections removed:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:template match="show_details">

    <html>
....
<xsl:element name="img">
  <xsl:attribute name="class">
    show_images
  </xsl:attribute>
  <xsl:attribute name="alt">
    <xsl:value-of select="show_image/image_alt_text"/>
  </xsl:attribute>
  <xsl:attribute name="src">
    <xsl:value-of select="show_image/image_path"/>
  </xsl:attribute>
</xsl:element>
....More HTML
</html> 
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I have also tried simply inserting the image using the following method:

```
<img src="{show_image/image_path}"/>
```

Neither method seems to work on IOS or Android phones.

Comment: This isn't really a programming question, is it?

Comment: The complete xpath of your url from the `show_details` context node would be `production/show_image/image_path` and you might want to put `normalize-space(production/show_image/image_path)` around it

Comment: Thank you Stefan, your suggestion to add `normalize-space()` seems to be the answer.